# How to configure Unbound to use DNSSEC?

Tags: dns

I'm having a local caching DNS server: Unbound:

```
[root@localhost /etc/unbound] cat unbound.conf
server:
    interface: 127.0.0.1
    access-control: 127.0.0.1 allow 
    verbosity: 1
    harden-referral-path: yes  
    use-caps-for-id: yes
    prefetch: yes  
    prefetch-key: yes
[root@localhost /etc/unbound]
```

Rebooted the notebook, cleaned the browser, and go to:

http://dnssec.vs.uni-due.de/

it says:

**No, your DNS resolver does NOT validate DNSSEC signatures.**

..What am I missing?

UPDATE: 
http://dnssectest.sidn.nl/ - says this too.. according to "dig" I'm using 127.0.0.1 for DNS server..

I tried service iptables stop..didn't worked.

BTW, why do stackexchange look like this ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9DP0.png ) when I'm using a local DNS cache?

Comment: BTW because your local DNS cache is failing to resolve the server used for StackOverflow's CSS.  Install Firebug on Firefox and look at the HTTP tab.

Comment: Where did you get unbound from?  I'm wondering if you're lacking the public keys...

Comment: I got it from the EPEL repo

Comment: "BTW" - how can I resolv this issue? why doesn't it resolves it? :D

Comment: "BTW" - Manpage says you can set `verbose: 3` to get per-query information into the log.  Or start by finding what the failing domain is and then running dig manually to see the result code.

Comment: [Unbound: Howto enable DNSSEC [2011]](http://www.unbound.net/documentation/howto_anchor.html).

But the Fedora package already does this (in the default config).  So it might be you removed a line like `auto-trust-anchor-file: "/var/lib/unbound/root.key"` which the package provided as the default config.  If that's the case then just put that line back, run `sudo -u unbound unbound-anchor`, and then it will work :-).